# ImportError: Cannot import name OAuthHandler Foursquare Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, foursquare

I am trying to run the code in foursquare wrapper by [marcelcaraciolo](https://github.com/marcelcaraciolo) but I constantly get this error can any one help me solve this?

```
AttributeError: 'module' Object has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'
```

Code is Below

```
import foursquare

# == OAuth2 Authentication ==
#
# This mode of authentication is the required one for Foursquare

# The client id and client secret can be found on your application's Details
# page located at https://foursquare.com/oauth/
client_id = "sasa"
client_secret = "xyz"
callback = ''

auth = foursquare.OauthHandler(client_id, client_secret, callback)

#First Redirect the user who wish to authenticate to.
#It will be create the authorization url for your app
auth_url = auth.get_authorization_url()
print ('Please authorize: ' + auth_url)

#If the user accepts, it will be redirected back
#to your registered REDIRECT_URI.
#It will give you a code as
#https://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/?code=CODE
code = raw_input('The code: ').strip()

#Now your server will make a request for
#the access token. You can save this
#for future access for your app for this user
access_token = auth.get_access_token(code)
print ('Your access token is ' + access_token)
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think it is `OAuthHandler`. Capitalization matters my friend!

Comment: @JoshKopen Thank you for your reply, nope it doesnt help either :(

Comment: Is it still the same error message?

Comment: @joshkopen Yup same error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'module' Object has no attribute 'OAuthHandler'`

Comment: Does it happen to have a folder in the workspace named **forsquare**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pyfoursquare as foursquare
```

[foursquare eg](https://github.com/marcelcaraciolo/foursquare/blob/master/examples/oauth.py)

Do you have `pyfoursquare` ?

do

```
>>> dir(foursquare)
```

and check if you have `OAuthHandler` listed ?